# SQL Server insert statement runs successfully but values are not added to table even though row is created

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an insert statement as below. I am able to debug my stored procedure and step through my code to verify that my code runs, but a funny thing happens.

The values that I expect to be saved in the database are not saved. Instead a row is created in the table and the `RecordCreatedField` is correctly created, even a primary key is included but the actual columns I expect to be inserted are not. All the columns are `nvarchar/varchar`, except for the date columns and the ID, but only those columns are populated.  However the following **@PRCUPC ,@PRCEAN ,@PRCGTIN,@PRCatalogNumber** are somehow omitted.

```
EXEC spinsertprodcode 
                  @pid out, 
                  @ProdID, 
                  @UPC, 
                  @EAN, 
                  @TIN, 
                  @CNumber, 
                  0, 
                  0, 
                  1, 
                  @staid, 
                  @counter out



INSERT INTO dbo.ProdCodes
(PRProductID
,PRCUPC
,PRCEAN
,PRCGTIN
,PRCatalogNumber
,PRIsReplacement 
,PRIsReplaced 
,PRCRecordCreatedDate 
,PRCIsActive
,PRStatusFlag)

OUTPUT INSERTED.PRCID INTO @opID

VALUES
(@PRProductID, 
@PRCUPC, 
@PRCEAN, 
@PRCGTIN, 
@PRCatalogNumber,
@PRIsReplacement ,
@PRIsReplaced,
GETDATE(), 
@PRCIsActive, 
@PRStatusFlag)

SELECT @PRCID = O.ID FROm @opID O
```

Would appreciate any suggestion on how I can fix this  or understand what is going on.

[image: Image of the Debug Screen where I confirm the right values are passed]

Here is an SQl fiddle of the main Stored proc that calls my insert code. 
[**SQL Fiddle of my code**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/9)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to call the stored procedure? I'd take a guess that the parameters aren't being set correctly maybe.

Comment: I am able to hover over the values to confirm that they are correctly passed in. And I step into the called code to the insert point and am able to also verify the values are there even to install point.

Comment: Is there a trigger on the table?

Comment: I created this database using SSMS on this particular server. Please remember that a row is created but instead of adding the  values @PRCUPC ,@PRCEAN ,@PRCGTIN,@PRCatalogNumber are skipped however, the other values in my insert are added.

Comment: I didn't add any triggers to my table.

Comment: Actually the complete SP definition would be of interest so we could test run exactly the same SP. And if it is a bug SP then create the smallest subset of it that fails.

Comment: The complete SP that makes the call to the insert which does not happen is available at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/9. Somehow the wrong values are probably being passed but when I use SSMS SQL debugger to check the code, the right values are passed but not saved.

Comment: The only thing i see in the fiddle is a select date(), probably it is overwritten. Please post it again

Comment: Really want to help, but if there is no feedback things are getting tough....

Comment: The SQL Fiddle link is just select date()

Answer (score 1):

@Kobojunkie: This kind of issues can be easily managed if you follow one of the golden rules of T-SQL Best Practices: use a TRY/CATCH block to wrap your code for INSERT and DELETE statements. Having an approapiate CATCH block including system variables like ERROR_NUMBER, ERROR_SEVERITY, ERROR_PROCEDURE, ERROR_LINE and ERROR_MESSAGE will give you clues about what's going wrong with the action being performed:

```
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT @ErrorDetails = 
            N'Error raised when executing [Insert/Delete] statement: '
            + N' SQL Error: ' + ERROR_NUMBER()
            + N', Level: ' + ERROR_SEVERITY()
            + N', Line: ' + ERROR_LINE()
            + N', Message: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE() 
END CATCH
```

Hope this information helps to fix the issue within the sproc!